# On Install, which code sets the 'home' option?

Tags: customization, homepage, options, installation

I'm just doing some wordpress development and wondered for a brand new install, which code within core is generating the first value that get's filled into the `home` option?

I'm looking for the code in core, e.g. the filename and the line where this happens.

Does someone remembers from mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the installer runs it calls `wp_install()`, that in turn calls `populate_options()` defined in `wp-admin/includes/schema.php`, which runs the following..

```
if ( !__get_option('home') ) update_option('home', $guessurl);
```

Prior to that `$guessurl` is defined by..

```
$guessurl = wp_guess_url();
```

The guess URL function is defined in `wp-includes/functions.php` and looks like this.

```
function wp_guess_url() {
    if ( defined('WP_SITEURL') && '' != WP_SITEURL ) {
        $url = WP_SITEURL;
    } else {
        $schema = is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $url = preg_replace('|/wp-admin/.*|i', '', $schema . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
    return rtrim($url, '/');
}
```

- wp_install()
  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L22
- populate_options()
  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/includes/schema.php#L177
- guess_url()
  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L3585

Hope that's the info you're looking for... :)

Comment: Related ticket is [#16884](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16884).

Comment: @t3los -- There's not much room for improvement on your answer. Would you care to share any of the tools you used to look up this information? Maybe you did it manually, but I'm wondering if you have any tricks up your sleeve... Maybe it's worth it to figure out how to use [phpdoc](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/branches/3.1/)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just did it by hand, me, notepad++ and 5 minutes of spare time. Notepad++ can scan through all the WordPress PHP files for a string of text within a minute(it's usually faster/easier to do that than it is to search the web/codex/other-sources). Sorry if you were expecting something more elaborate ... :)

Comment: No need for an apology, it's a testament to your helpfulness. Unfortunately, my hardware seems to dislike Notepad++. Editing three characters in a MySQL dump of a single (but large -- 60MB) WordPress table, took about an hour while my (fairly well equiped) PC struggled to open and save the bytes.